# Swift presentViewController

Tags: swift, ios8, viewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I programatically have multiple View Controllers in an iOS Swift Project. I do not have the storyboards and would like to avoid them if possible. Is there a way to switch to another `viewcontroller.swift` file (We will call it `view2.swift`) and have it be part of a function that a button calls?
I have tried the following:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myTabBarName", bundle: nil)
let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myVCID") as UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The above works with storyboards, but I want another `view2.swift` to be called. Can this be done?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Try this:

```
let vc = ViewController() //change this to your class name
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

With Swift3:

```
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the initializer: `ViewController(nibNameOrNil: nil, bundleOrNil: nil)`

Comment: Thank you! This ended up working. It is also much simpler than the old way to do it in Objective-C, which I guess was the whole point of swift. Thanks again!

Comment: @Adam, I am doing exactly same to show view on a button click. It shows up black blank screen. There are no errors. Any idea why am I getting black screen?

Comment: @Sanjivani, From iOS7, the default color of the view is clear color, So it show black screen. Set color in VIewController's viewDidLoad as                      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}

Comment: this will occur blank screen !

Comment: @Sanjivani you have explicitly type the nib file name, so instead of "let vc = ViewController()" type "let vc = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)".
This will solve your problem.

Comment: How is this accepted and vote up so many times, its not even using initializer for viewcontroller, do like this will result in nothing

Comment: Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'present'

Comment: @Oleksandr `AppDelegate` is not a view controller. You could try `self.rootViewController.present( ...` but this can depend on your use case and your app architecture.

Comment: Totally wrong approach, with this method, you only create a new ViewController instance not VC in the storyboard.

Comment: @OnderOZCAN this is exactly right approach when you don’t use storyboards

Comment: Oh sorry I missed the title "Programmatically" my bad :(

Comment: If you get a black screen is because you are not instantiating your controller form a xib/nib/storyboard

Answer (score 112):

For those getting blank/black screens this code worked for me.

```
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: myVCID) as! myVCName
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

To set the "Identifier" to your VC just go to identity inspector for the VC in the storyboard. Set the 'Storyboard ID' to what ever you want to identifier to be. Look at the image below for reference.
[image]

Comment: @KD. except that the question asked to do it without storyboards.

Answer (score 21):

*For reference, because this question is one of the first Google result.*

### Breaking change in Swift 3:

The method `presentViewController` is replaced by the method `present`.

You can use it like the old one:

```
self.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Example to open the camera:

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.delegate = self
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 19):

**Swift 3 and Swift 4**

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idMyViewControllerName") as! MyViewControllerName
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 8):

For me, I had two views in two separate nav controllers. I had to use a combination of the above.

```
var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WelcomeViewController") as! WelcomeViewController
    var navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

### Swift 3.x

```
        let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC-ID" as! yourViewController
        let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
        self.present(navigationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Using Swift 2.1+**

```
 let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("settingsVC") as! SettingsViewController
 self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Solved the black screen by adding a navigation controller and setting the second view controller as rootVC.

```
let vc = ViewController()       
var navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use this : Make sure using nibName otherwise preloaded views of xib will not show :

`var vc : ViewController =  ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)` //change this to your class name

```
 self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to instantiate the ViewController in Storyboard just to get `present()` ViewController to work. That's a hackish solution.

If you see a **black/blank screen** when presenting a VC, it might be because you're calling `present()` from `viewDidLoad()` in the First/RootViewController, but the first View isn't ready yet.

Call `present()` from `viewDidAppear` to fix this, i.e.:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let yourVC = YourViewController()
    self.present(yourVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Once any "View" has appeared in your App, you can start calling present() from `viewDidLoad()`.

---

Using `UINavigationController` (as suggested in an answer) is another option, but it might be an overkill to solve this issue. You might end up complicating the user flow. Use the `UINavigationController` based solution only if you want to have a NavigatonBar or want to return to the previous view controller.

Answer (score 1):

It's already answered. But adding one more thing while presenting a `UIViewController`, If anyone is trying to add [UIModalPresentationStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle)  :

if directly presenting the `UIViewController` as fullScreen:

```
let viewController = UIViewController()
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(viewController, animated: true)
```

If there is `UINavigationController` with root view controller as `UIViewController`:

```
let viewController = UIViewController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(navigationController, animated: true)
```

More helpful answers:

- [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code :

```
var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewController") as! YourViewController;
            vc.mode_Player = 1
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you do not have the XIB included in your Build target (which is what happened to me).

This could happen if you have a different target for Dev, Test & Release Builds (which you should have anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but in my case, the solution was to dispatch the action as an async task in the main queue

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: myVCID) as! myVCName
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use code:

```
if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as? secondViewController {
   let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
   appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = vc
}
```