# Open a new TabBarController on clicking a tableview cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I am novice to Swift, how can open a new TabBarController on clicking a tableviewcell. Awaiting for your responses

Comment: IF you are using storyboards just drag & drop a segue from the cell it self to the newly created TabBarController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have number of good solutions:
1) **If you're using storyboards,** then control+drag from the cell to your `TabBarController`.
2) **If you want to do it with code** and you're using `UINavigationController` try to do this with push to Nav:

```
let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as! ViewController
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(VC1, animated: true)
```

3) If you don't have `UINavigationController` you can just present the VC like this:

```
let VC1 = ViewController() //change this to your class name
self.presentViewController(VC1, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

4) If you're using Nibs (previous with this minor change):

```
ViewController(nibNameOrNil: nil, bundleOrNil: nil)
```

If you want more resources, you can check out this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099533/swift-presentviewcontroller)

Comment: Thanks for the solution Dragos, It really helpedme a lot

Comment: Nice to hear that :-)