# UIButton, Mapbox, Open new View programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, mapbox

I am a beginner, and i can't understand one thing.
In this [example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/callout-delegate/) there exist Info button. As I understand there piece of code returns this button:

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, rightCalloutAccessoryViewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> UIView? {
    return UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
}
```

So the question is: how can I open another View (view name: extraInfo, viewcontroller's name: extraInfoController) from this button programmatically? 
Please, can u reply in detail, because as i already sad, I am beginner. :)
(I am using Swift, not Obj-C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this delegate method

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotation: MGLAnnotation, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

}
```

Comment: Would you be able to answer a little more in detail? How can I open new View? Srry for this questions, but I am beginner and trying to understand this thing)

Comment: If you want to present view from this, you have to use this: self.presentViewController(VC, animated: true, completion: nil). Here VC is view controller which you can present

Comment: If you are unaware of presenting view controller. This link may helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099533/swift-presentviewcontroller