# Disable the interactive dismissal of presented view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit, modalviewcontroller, ios13

**iOS 13** introduces a new design of `modalPresentationStyle` `.pageSheet` (and its sibling `.formSheet`) for modally presented view controllers…

[image: The new sliding modal presentation in iOS 13]

…and we can dismiss these sheets by sliding the presented view controller down *(interactive dismissal)*. Although the new "pull-to-dismiss" feature is pretty useful, it may not always be desirable.

**THE QUESTION:** How can we turn the interactive dismissal off? 
*- Bear in mind we keep the presentation style the same.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Comment: @MehulThakkar That's a different question.

Answer (score 439, accepted):

#### Option 1:

```
viewController.isModalInPresentation = true
```

[image: Disabled interactive dismissal]

*(Disabled interactive `.pageSheet` dismissal acts like this.)*

- Since the iOS 13, `UIViewController` contains a new property called `isModalInPresentation` which must be set to `true` to prevent the interactive dismissal.
- It basically ignores events outside the view controller's bounds. Bear that in mind if you are using not only the automatic style but also presentation styles like `.popover` etc.
- This property is `false` by default.

> **From the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/3229894-modalinpresentation?language=objc)**: If `true`, UIKit ignores events outside the view controller's bounds and prevents the interactive dismissal of the view controller while it is onscreen.

---

#### Option 2:

```
func presentationControllerShouldDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

- Since the iOS 13, `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` contains a new method called `presentationControllerShouldDismiss`.
- This method is called only if the presented view controller is not dismissed programmatically and its `isModalInPresentation` property is set to `false`.

> **Tip:** Don't forget to assign `presentationController`'s delegate. But be aware, it is known that even just accessing the `presentationController` can cause a memory leak.

Comment: If the presented view controller is a navigation controller, you can either set `isModalInPresentation` on the navigation controller or on the individual view controllers shown in the navigation stack. The latter allows you to choose on a screen-by-screen basis whether the interactive dismissal is possible. Careful with search controllers, they take precedence over the individual view controller (but not the navigation controller). More info in my blog post: https://medium.com/@hacknicity/view-controller-presentation-changes-in-ios-13-ac8c901ebc4e

Comment: Keep in mind that if your VC is presented as a popover, this will prevent the popover from being dismissed when tapping outside of it

Comment: Objective-C: `viewController.modalInPresentation = YES;`

Comment: Anyone got this to work when setting this flag on a `UIImagePickerController`? For us it looks like the `UIImagePickerController` is ignoring it and so it can be dismissed with the swipe gesture. Maybe it's an iOS 13 bug.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/disabling_pulling_down_a_sheet

Comment: When `presentationControllerShouldDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController)` returns false, `presentationControllerDidAttemptToDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController)` is called so you can do things like add a confirmation dialogue if the user has entered data.

Comment: I'm also seeing issues when using a `UIImagePickerController`, `presentationControllerShouldDismiss` is ignored but other delegate functions such as  `presentationControllerWillDismiss` are called.

Answer (score 91):

1. If you want the same behaviour as it's in previous iOS version (< iOS13) like model presentation in fullscreen, just set the presentation style of your destination view controller to `UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen`

   ```
   let someViewController = \*VIEW CONTROLLER*\
   someViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
   ```

   And if you are using storyboard just select the segua and select `Full Screen` form the `Presentation` dropdown.

   [image]
2. If you just want to disable the interactive dismissal and keep the new presentation style set `UIViewController` property `isModalInPresentation` to `true`.

   ```
   if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
       someViewController.isModalInPresentation = true // available in IOS13
   }
   ```

Comment: It works better than using {controller.isModalInPresentation = true
}.

Comment: Does second approach work with previous iOS version? < iOS13.0

Answer (score 12):

The property `isModalInPresentation` might help.

From the documentation:

> When you set it to `true`, UIKit ignores events outside the view controller's bounds and prevents the interactive dismissal of the view controller while it is onscreen.

You can use it like this:

```
let controller = MyViewController()
controller.isModalInPresentation = true
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 10):

If you have some business logic, something like all fields should be filled before dismissing, you should:

On `ViewDidLoad` if your ViewController has been presented within a Navigation Controller:

```
func viewDidLoad() { 
    self.navigationController?.presentationController?.delegate = self
}
```

If not, simply use

```
func viewDidLoad() { 
    self.presentationController?.delegate = self
}
```

Then implement the delegate method:

```
extension ViewController: UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {

    func presentationControllerShouldDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) -> Bool {
        guard let text = firstName.text, text.isEmpty else { return false }
        guard let text = lastName.text, text.isEmpty else { return false }
        ...
    
        return true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using storyboards to layout your UI I have found the best way to disable this interactive dismissal when using a navigation controller is to change the presentation of the Navigation Controller in the attribute inspector from Automatic to Full Screen. All view controllers in your navigation stack will then be full screen and will not be able to be dismissed by the user.

[Attribute Inspector showing presentation option for the navigation controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqHli.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Apple shared a sample code about it [at this link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/disabling_pulling_down_a_sheet)

It uses `isModalInPresentation` as many users suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

i was try to so hard for solve this problem but the solution are work for me is i select ViewController in **mainstoryboard > inspector > presentation > Full Screen ** default **Automatic** to change **FullScreen**

it's work for me

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.

Answer (score -2):

All solutions are good, but in my case, I need an option to stop movement.
So this is a code for that.

if you want to block movement:

```
self.yourViewController?.presentedView?.gestureRecognizers?[0].isEnabled = false
```

And if you want to unblock movement:

```
self.yourViewController?.presentedView?.gestureRecognizers?[0].isEnabled = true
```