# How disable drag dismiss in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have UIViewController add to my view by present. 
Now user can remove this view by drag to bottom of screen. How can I disable it?

I try by

```
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

and

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.transitioningDelegate = self
    }

extension MyViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func interactionControllerForDismissal(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return nil
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

But user still can dismiss it.

Comment: As I understand your view controller implement some custom logic to be dismissed by drag to bottom. Probably it's some pan gesture recognizer in controller implementation or in parent controller implementation. You just need remove/disable it.

Comment: @AntonRodzik - no, I don't have any custom logic. This is default. In this view controller I only set cornerRadius and text in label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need disable your pan gesture to disable drag dismiss.

Comment: I try 
`if let gesutreRecognize = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.gestureRecognizers {
            for gesture in gesutreRecognize where gesture is UIPanGestureRecognizer {
                gesture.isEnabled = false
            }
        }`
In ViewWillAppear and ViewDidLoad and still didn't work

Comment: Can you put your full sample proj?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. NDA :)

Comment: Because gesture you need disable maybe from another screen that control your dismiss. Please find it from parent controller or another container controller.

Comment: Yeah, now I'm doing it, and I think it might work :)

Comment: Ok, I found the solution. Just like @Than Vu wrote, I using another screen to control my view. I used PopupDialog framework(https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog), and when I init it, I add

`panGestureDismissal: false`
And now works fine :)

Comment: @JamesVoo congratulation

Answer (score 1):

See Bilal's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459329/disable-the-interactive-dismissal-in-ios-13/56485962#56485962)

.isModalInPresentation = true worked for me

Comment: Thanks, but I must support older version of iOS :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line in the viewController's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

You can refer [this](https://medium.com/swift2go/simple-custom-uinavigationcontroller-transitions-fdb56a217dd8).

Comment: It's renamed to       `self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false` but still don't work