# iOS 16: Set Minimum Detent for sheetPresentationController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisheetpresentationcontroller

Is there a way in iOS 16's expanded `UISheetPresentationController` API to set a minimum detent height for a presented sheet? (i.e. such that it does not dismiss from the screen?)

Example presentation code:

```
let viewControllerToPresent = UIViewController()
if let sheet = viewControllerToPresent.sheetPresentationController {
    sheet.detents = [.medium(), .large()]
    sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .medium
    sheet.prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge = false
    sheet.prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight = true
    sheet.widthFollowsPreferredContentSizeWhenEdgeAttached = true
    }
present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Does adding `viewControllerToPresent.isModalInPresentation = true` do what you are looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable the interactive dismissal of presented view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459329/disable-the-interactive-dismissal-of-presented-view-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `viewControllerToPresent.isModalInPresentation = true` as a property enables this experience.