# How set rootViewController in Scene Delegate iOS 13

Tags: swift, uikit, ios13

Before changes in UIKit iOS 13 how I can set rootViewController at SceneDelegate?

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    }
```

Answer (score 41):

FYI since SwiftUI doesn't use storyboards if you just make a new SwiftUI project it will give you the code; all you need to do is replace the UIHostingViewController with your desired root VC like this:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = MyRootViewController()
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 15):

If you ever find yourself needing to access the window from the delegate (both iOS12 & iO13)to change the rootviewcontroller here's a couple of extensions I use:

```
   extension UIViewController {
        var appDelegate: AppDelegate {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }
    
    var sceneDelegate: SceneDelegate? {
        guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
            let delegate = windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate else { return nil }
         return delegate
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    var window: UIWindow? {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
                let delegate = windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate, let window = delegate.window else { return nil }
                   return window
        }
        
        guard let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = delegate.window else { return nil }
        return window
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support multi window support just ignore it. I follow up [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57467270/4320266).

When you start new project with it's automatically creates manifest and SceneDelegate class. After ignore multi window support, you can use app delegate window again like before.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

   var window: UIWindow?
   func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
         // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
         // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
         // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

        let rootVC = self.window?.rootViewController 
    }
    // ... the rest of SceneDelegate
}
```

As seen [here](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/blog/ios-development/ui-work/accessing-root-view-controller-ios13-scenedelegate/).