# SceneDelegate switch between uiwindows in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I need to load a uiwindow from my storyboard and place this above all other windows. From what I've seen online the process for this has changed with iOS 13.

I'm aware of other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188296/how-set-rootviewcontroller-in-scene-delegate-ios-13) that show how to set a new root VC at start up. However I need to change rootVCs back and forth between multiple view controllers within my storyboard based on user action.

At the moment I'm running the following 'pre-ios13' code but I'm getting warnings that this approach is no longer supported.

```
blackoutWindow.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
blackoutWindow.backgroundColor = .black
blackoutWindow.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.statusBar + 1
blackoutWindow.rootViewController = self as? UIViewController
blackoutWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: why you need to switch windows instead of ViewControllers??

Comment: I need for the second controller or window to complete cover the original window, which has an avplayer instance playing a video. Can I do that with a VC?

Comment: I think so, you can use containers for several view controllers in one view controller. I'm not 100% sure about the case with the AVPlayer but I think it is a good option to give a try. Instead of changing the window.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks