# userId coming to appdelegate still not going to Mainviewcontroller why? in swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, userid, rootviewcontroller

**NavigationController** is `isinitial viewcontroller in storyboard`, NavigationController embedded to LoginViewcontroller

in project storyboard navigation willbe like below

```
NavigationController->LoginViewcontroller-> RegistrationViewcontroller -> MainViewcontroller
```

in successful registration with PhNUmber i am getting `userId` which i have stored in KeychainWrapper

**in RegistrationViewcontroller:** i am storing userId like below:

```
 let userID: String=jsonObj?["userId"] as? String ?? "" 
 KeychainWrapper.standard.set(userID, forKey: "USERID")
```

**which i am checking in appdelegate** like below to go Mainviewcontroller:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var savedUserId: String?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    savedUserId = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "USERID")
    print("appdelegate userid \(savedUserId)")
    if savedUserId != nil{
        print("saveuserid \(savedUserId)")
        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        window?.rootViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController")
    }
    return true
}
}
```

here `savedUserId` coming then why i am not going to MainViewcontroller, all the time LoginViewcontroller appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the `window`. Give this line above setting the `rootViewController`:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var savedUserId: String?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        savedUserId = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "USERID")
        print("appdelegate userid \(savedUserId)")
        if savedUserId != nil{
            print("saveuserid \(savedUserId)")
            let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            window = UIWindow()
            window?.rootViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController")
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Update: If you're using `SceneDelegate` you should use this:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)print("appdelegate userid \(savedUserId)")
        if savedUserId != nil{
            print("saveuserid \(savedUserId)")
            let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            window = UIWindow()
            window?.rootViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if i give like this `var window = UIWindow()` then error: Type of 'window' has different optionality than required by protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'

Comment: var window: UIWindow? and in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in window = UIWindow()
window?.rootViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController")............then also login viewcontroller appears

Comment: I doubt If you're providing your answer as I expect. So I've updated my answer to the entire code that you've provided.

Comment: both userid coming appdelegate userid Optional("415c6073d45a481f991cb81b4c81bf81")
saveuserid Optional("415c6073d45a481f991cb81b4c81bf81").   but loginviewcontroller coming

Comment: Could you check if `mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") != nil` is getting `true`.

Comment: @iOSApp If you're using SceneDelegate you should be using the update I've just posted.

Comment: SceneDelegate file is there but i am not using.. i am using appdelegate only

Comment: That doesn't count. If you're not using SceneDelegate then delete it and remove its reference from `info.plist`.

Comment: oh yeah I have deleted both SceneDelegate file and its reference then its working.. thanks for that information

Comment: if there is a chance pls suggest me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63406320/how-to-stop-autofilling-address-in-textfields-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

Try using this extension

```
  // add this function in your AppDelegate

  func makeRootVC(_ storyBoardName : String, _ vcName : String) {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        self.window?.rootViewController = nav
        let options: UIView.AnimationOptions = .transitionCrossDissolve
        let duration: TimeInterval = 0.6
        UIView.transition(with: self.window!, duration: duration, options: options, animations: {}, completion: nil)
    }
```

then use it like this in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    savedUserId = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "USERID")
    print("appdelegate userid \(savedUserId)")
    if savedUserId != nil{
        print("saveuserid \(savedUserId)")
        self.makeRootVC("Main","MainViewController")
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: UIView.transition(with: self.window!, duration: duration, options: options, animations: {}, completion: nil).    error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @iOSApp Are you using `SceneDelegate` too ?

Comment: yes SceneDelegate is there, but in the same line same error

Comment: @iOSApp Refer this for setting rootViewController from sceneDelegate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188296/how-set-rootviewcontroller-in-scene-delegate-ios-13

Answer (score 1):

check if window is nil and add makeKeyAndVisible() after setting rootViewController in AppDelegate

```
if(window == nil){
    self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)
}
if savedUserId != nil{
    print("saveuserid \(savedUserId)")
    let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    window?.rootViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController")
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: if i print userid in `if(window == nil){` both prints but not going to mainviewcontroller