# Unrecognized selector sending self.window message in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions when creating a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm working through the Big Nerd Ranch iOS Programming book (4th ed, which focuses on Objective C) using XCode 11 and I am having trouble sorting out how to add a UIView.

As soon as I send this message in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

`self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];`

I get an unrecognized selector message.

I've tried removing the launch and main storyboards with no success, and enabling multiple windows. This is in a single view app project (perhaps I should just try an empty project?)

What am I missing or not understanding? I chose this book because I am trying to learn Objective-C (not Swift) and the debugger doesn't tell me much about what's wrong here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial dates back to pre `UIWindowSceneDelegate` days.

The Prewindowscene era (joke)

The reason your code is syntactically correct is that `AppDelegate` conforms to the protocol `UIApplicationDelegate` which declares `window` but without the property declaration on the class you'll get the exception

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate setWindow:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance ...'

If you look at the generated template project you'll probably see

`AppDelegate.h/.m` &  `SceneDelegate.h/.m`

`SceneDelegate.h` is where you'll find the declaration:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow * window;
```

While you technically could add that line in

```
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions
```

That doesn't make any sense as the `UIWindow` instance is created by the storyboard system for you.

My instinct would be to skip that chunk of the tutorial and work through the other elements using the supplied `UIWindow` from `SceneDelegate`.

Alternatively if you have your heart set on the original tutorial you can opt out of [scene mechanics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467003/xcode-11-opt-out-of-uiscenedelegate-swiftui-on-ios-13) and add the line

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow * window;
```

to `AppDelegate.h`

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation.