# MultipeerConnectivity does not work as expected on iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity, ios14

When the `MCBrowserViewController` is invoked

```
-[MCBrowserViewController advertiser:didNotStartAdvertisingPeer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

error message is thrown.

when `MCAdvertiserAssistant` tries starts advertising

```
-[MCAdvertiserAssistant advertiser:didNotStartAdvertisingPeer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

error message is thrown.

Struck and unable to proceed. My business depends on `MultipeerConnectivity` framework.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

```
let assistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "tictactoe", discoveryInfo: nil, session: session)
let browser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "tictactoe", session: session)
```

Insert in the info.plist the following fields:

1. Privacy - Local Network Usage Description
2. Bonjour services with the following initialisation: _tictactoe._tcp and _tictactoe._udp

[image]
[image]

Comment: What are these value actually?_tictactoe._tcp and _tictactoe._udp

Comment: Thanks for your answer actually this solution does not solve the issue. Btw the issue is not happening in Simulator.

Comment: Those are the identifiers you are using while creating the advertiser and browser.

Comment: What value should i use ?

Comment: How do you create your MCBrowserViewController  and MCAdvertiserAssistant? Can you show your code?

Comment: advertiser = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: identifier, discoveryInfo: nil, session: session)
        browserController = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: identifier, session: session)

Comment: What is the value of the identifier variable?

Comment: both are same "PARTY_ID"

Comment: so you should add as _PARTY_ID._tcp and _PARTY_ID._udp

Comment: Crash got fixed but the connection gets declined now. you got any idea?

Comment: I am unable to see Hosted Device while Joining session. Please help guys

Answer (score 2):

i did face some issues implementing `MultipeerConnectivity` too. After some research found a fix..
what i did was

1. i followed https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/networking/how-to-create-a-peer-to-peer-network-using-the-multipeer-connectivity-framework this.
2. added `Bonjour services` (value- `_*serviceType*._tcp`) and  `Privacy - Local Network Usage Description` in `Info.plist`.
3. removed `SceneDelegate` related stuff as in [Opt out of UISceneDelegate/SwiftUI on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467003/opt-out-of-uiscenedelegate-swiftui-on-ios)

clean and build.

**Note:i** am working with Xcode12 and iOS14.

Comment: Crash got fixed but the connection gets declined now. you got any idea?