# Xcode 11 is Showing all Screens Behind current Presented Screen

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, xcode11

After updating my xcode all my screens that have navigation controller look like the below image. It looks like all the screens under the navigationController are showing behind each other for the root navController Also it worked fine on previous Xcode versions.

[image]
Any sugggestions?

Comment: This is not Xcode 11. This is how iOS 13 looks.

Comment: @rmaddy i am using Xcode 11 and running it on an iOS13 on the simulator

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't very clear. The behavior you are seeing is a function of iOS 13, not Xcode 11. If you use Xcode 11 to run on an iOS 12 device (or simulator), you will see the old behavior.

Comment: Since what you are seeing is correct behavior and there is no issue, there's no answer to provide. However, if you decide to avoid the new iOS 13 behavior (but you shouldn;t), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen

Comment: ok thanks i looked at ur link and added an answer here

Answer (score 0):

to get the behaviour I want I had to :

Set my UITabController  **present** to FullScreen as shown in pic below then all navigationControllers screens/v were fullscreen

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting this answer, let's close your question as a duplicate of the one I linked.