# iOS 13.1 Objective-C ModalPresentation Fullscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13, xcode11

found next strange bug in iOS 13 presenting modally over fullscreen viewcontroller. Initially it was broken, it was opened in not a full screen so I tried next method described on
[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)
Now it loads and awaits touch to anywhere on the screen. 
Currently this is Parent viewController, which should modally show TermsVC

```
mainView.hidden = YES;
        IDTermsViewController *termsVC = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDTermsViewController"];
        termsVC.delegate = self;
        if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
            [termsVC setModalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
        }
        [self presentViewController:termsVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Currently after presenting this termsVC, i've got the next state like on the screenshot below. If i do any action - shake the phone, make screenshot, tap anywhere - TermsVC will appear!

On previous ios version works fine.
[image]

Comment: It was not initially broken. iOS 13 changes the default presentation of modals. Don't fight it, embrace it.

Comment: First thing you should do is add a proper Launch Screen Storyboard to your app to eliminate the black bars at the top and bottom of your screen.

Comment: Unrelated but there's no need to check for iOS 13 to set the presentation style to full screen. That code is valid on earlier versions of iOS too.

Comment: @maddy I think you better put it as an answer to be accepted, thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 7):

try removing this

```
 if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
     [termsVC setModalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
  }
```

then just adding this

```
  termsVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
```

this nullifies the iOS 13 presentation wackiness

Comment: I tried multiple answers from StackOverflow but only this answer works perfectly.