# When I updated the Xcode, in my app, my root view controller can be seen at the top of the current view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So when I drag it down the app will dismiss the current view an go to there. I don't want it, how should I fix it? Everything was okay till update

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 13, the default modal presentation is sheet, which is what you got.

To get the old modal style, do:

```swift
loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
```

Answer (score 0):

In the iOS 13 SDK the color handling changed crucially due to the introduction of Dark Mode.

Set the background color of the current view to System Background color.

And consider that all modally presented view controllers are presented as sheet by default.

Comment: To expand on the last comment, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen