# iOS 13 new presentation styles - presenting VC not shrinking down

Tags: ios, ios13, modalviewcontroller

I am having a problem with the new VC presentation styles in iOS 13. I want to implement the new "stack" presentation.
However I do have an issue where the PRESENTING view controller is not shrinking down as it should causing a really ugly look.

The only solution I found to this problem is setting the background (ie presenting) VC as the new root view controller with

```
window.rootViewController = self
```

However this is not recommended by Apple and causes lots of odd bugs like dissapearing status bar or cutting of segue animations.
Can someone please explain to me how to fix this issue or how to properly use the new presentation styles or how to properly set a new root VC.

The intended behaviour:

[image: The intended behaviour]

The buggy behaviour:

[image: The buggy behaviour]

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen

Comment: This is not similar to my problem at all. I want to use the new presentation style, not get rid of it.