# modal UINavigationController bar with wrong height

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

**NOTE**: This is not about the new default modal presentation style used in iOS 13.

I have a strange issue presenting a modal `UINavigationController`.

Consider an `UIViewController` that is inside an `UINavigationController`:

[image]

When this code runs on iOS 13.0 :

```
@IBAction func btntap(_ sender: Any) {

    let errorViewController = UIViewController()
    errorViewController.view.backgroundColor = .blue
    errorViewController.title = "Erro na solicitação"

    let errorNavigation = UINavigationController()

    errorNavigation.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 204/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)

    errorNavigation.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    errorNavigation.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

    errorNavigation.setViewControllers([errorViewController], animated: false)

    errorNavigation.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic

    self.present(errorNavigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

This happens:

[image]

Note the wrong height when we present the modal screen on the first time:

[image]

I want to continue using the card-like presentation, but I need to fix this wrong height issue on the first present.

This happens when the following requirements are met:

1. The presenting `UIViewController` is inside an `UINavigationController`
2. The presented `UIViewController` has special chars on its title ("ç", "ã", etc)
3. The present is `animated true`

Already tried some variations of `layoutIfNeeded()` but none worked.

How can I present this with the right height on the first present?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Comment: Sorry, I searched a lot and didn't found any similar issue. The problem is the navigation bar height on the first present, not the presentation form. If the title is misleading, could you suggest a better one so I can edit the question?

Comment: This probably won't help but change `let errorNavigation = UINavigationController()` to `let errorNavigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: errorViewController)` and remove the line `errorNavigation.setViewControllers([errorViewController], animated: false)`.

Comment: No, same problem, but thank you for the try

Comment: Could you try to present from `self.navigationController` instead of just `self`? I've seen problems before when presenting from child controllers.

Comment: @Sulthan thanks for trying, but unfortunately the same issue occurs

Comment: This is a very well asked question, but can you explain how I can experience this bug? I pasted your code right into my project and it works fine for me.

Comment: @matt I uploaded an example [here](https://github.com/alxlives/navigationBug). I'm using Xcode 11.0 and iOS 13.0, I don't know if this issue is fixed on the newer iOS  versions.

Comment: Thanks! Your github example does elicit the bug. But when I write my own example with exactly the same code, it doesn't. Now I have to try to figure out what the difference is.

Comment: Okay! I figured it out. The bug is elicited only if the _source_ view controller is _also_ inside a navigation controller. I'd say this bug is completely solid; did you submit it to Apple?

Comment: Not yet, I will submit it now.

Comment: Bug reported - https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/7416163

Comment: Very nice work, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace the viewcontroller's title with your own label like so. this is a hack solution but will always work and you'll never have to think about it again. in fact, i never invoke the title property of viewcontrollers, i only use labels and set them as the titleView so i can control number of lines, subtitles, justification, etc.

```
    let errorViewController = UIViewController()
    errorViewController.view.backgroundColor = .blue

    let errorNavigation = UINavigationController()
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Erro na solicitação"
    label.textColor = .white

    errorViewController.navigationItem.titleView = label

    errorNavigation.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 204/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)

    errorNavigation.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

    errorNavigation.setViewControllers([errorViewController], animated: false)

    errorNavigation.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic

    self.present(errorNavigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

oh yes, and on that note, the font size should be around 17-18 from medium to bold to match ios default system for title value for viewController should you wish to match the ios system defaults

Comment: This feels a little hacky, but solved the problem. I will use it. Thank you very much!