# Xamarin forms: Previous screen is showing behind the current screen of ios app

Tags: macos, xamarin.forms

Found the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen). But the solution there not help me out.

Please have a look at the following screenshot of my xamarin forms ios app.

[image]

My problem is the previous page is showing behind the current screen. I am using visual studio for mac and Xcode 11.2.1 for development.

How can I get the fullscreen view for pages?

Comment: Could you share a sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Please wait, I will give you a sample ASAP

Comment: Don't forget to remove your personal info.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Sample project, please have a look. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ls3xN7B6L6dyO-2NkIMOVKvhDsrJp-1r

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I am using Xcode 11.2.1

Comment: It seems the version of XF in your project is still 3.3.x , try to update it to 4.3.x firstly .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202322/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Can you please post answer?

Comment: OK , I will post it with more details .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Xamarin.Forms in your project is still 3.3.x . Which could not compatible with the future in the latest version (4.3.x).So you should update the version of XF to at least 3.6.x .

Comment: Updating XF to latest version working fine for .net standard projects. Unfortunately, 2 of my projects are PCL. That's why the above errors are coming.

Do you have anything to add for the same issue in the PCL project?

Comment: PCL had been obsoleted in VS 2019 .

Comment: I tried to convert my PCL projects to .Net standard in VS 2019. Used `netstandard1.3` as `TargetFramework`. But getting below 3 errors at the final step.

![](https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/05/21xp1ldg8z5q.png "")