# How to prevent iOS 13 behaviour for appodeal fullscreen video ad?

Tags: ios, swift, appodeal

In iOS there is a new behaviour for modal view controller when being presented. Now it's not fullscreen by default and when I try to slide down, the app just dismiss the View Controller automatically.

How can I prevent this behaviour and get back to the old good fullscreen modal vc? I face this problem while using `appodeal` framework.

Code to show `videoad`

```
if Appodeal.isReadyForShow(with: .nonSkippableVideo){
    Appodeal.showAd(.nonSkippableVideo, rootViewController: self)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Comment: Best way to solve this problem - contact with Appodeal support and ask them to fix this issue

Comment: good. good. no one cares about ads anyway... but despite the joke, you may need to change the `modalPresentationStyle` explicitly to `fullScreen` (if you could) for the desired effect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it likely requires the third party to fix the issue, not the user.