# Swift 4.2 Segues: ViewControllers Stacking Instead of Replacing?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, segue, swift4.2

Pretty simple problem - now that I'm using Swift 4.2, my segues are "stacking" the view controllers physically. When I segue, the new view controller is not brought to the top of the screen and can be dragged down to go to the view controller before it. When I segue, I want the previous view controller to be entirely covered by the new one. How do I achieve this? Am I forced to use a navigation controller now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is a change in the *default* modal presentation style for iOS 13.  There are different possible ways to address it depending on your intent.  These question and answers cover those possibilities:

[Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Answer (score 0):

change the presentation style

for example

```
 let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sideMenu")
 VC1.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
 self[![enter image description here][1]][1].present(VC1, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or if you are using storyboard, check the segue properties

[image: segue properties]