# Switching between views in a Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Issue:

[image]

On the top, you can see the old view and if you hold the top of the second view and move to bottom the second view disappear.
I would like the second view to be **overlayed** on the first one.
First view has a button with an action:

```
@IBaction func test() {
    let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ccc")
    self.show( vc, sender: nil )
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `present`?

Comment: i try self.present(vc, animated: true) but it's getting the same result

Comment: @aaa55 check my answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Comment: yes thanks a lot, it's been several hours trying to figure out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `modalPresentationStyle` to `.fullScreen`.

```
//1
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ccc")

//2
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

//3
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: it's work thank, i can't validate answer yet but when modalPresentationStyle is not specified, xcode make a random choose ?

Comment: not random. its now default presentation style for iOS 13.0+ , for below version, it still shows them on fullScreen by default.