# I can't segue because Xcode is calling my Storyboard ID undeclared

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

On iOS, why am I getting the following error even though I assigned UserProfile to my StoryboardId:

> Use of undeclared type 'UserProfile'

Here's my code:

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

 guard let destinationVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserProfile") as? UserProfile else {
            return
        }

 navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: where did you implement UserProfile class?

Comment: in a separate file but the class is called userProfile

Comment: rename to UserProfile or change type cast to as? userProfile

Comment: the error went away but the segue isnt working

Comment: have you add identifier to your vc in storyboard?

Comment: I have the storyboard id but thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 guard let destinationVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourStoryBoardID") as? YourViewControllerClassName else {
            return
        }
```

`as? YourViewControllerClassName` You need to pass the name of the View Controller not the Storyboard ID here.

UPDATE:

As your current view controller is not embedded in navigationController,  `navigationController?.pushViewController` this returns nil and the line is not executed. To execute this line, your view controller should have a navigation controller.

To embed your controller in navigation Controller : [Follow point no:1 ,2 ,3 here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html)

If you do not want to use navigationController, you can use `presentViewController` instead.

```
guard let destinationVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourStoryBoardID") as? YourViewControllerClassName else {
            return
        }
self.present(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[Also learn about when to push and when to present a view controller](https://medium.com/@felicity.johnson.mail/pushing-popping-dismissing-viewcontrollers-a30e98731df5)

Comment: after changing it, there is no error but nothing happens on the segue

Comment: have you assigned the storyboardId and name of view controller correctly in your storyboard? Attach an image if possible.  Is your current controller in which you have placed this code is embedded in a navigation Controller?

Comment: i believe it is added properly but how do you embed a new controller in the navigation controller?

Comment: Follow point no:1 ,2 ,3 here : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html

Comment: Thank You the update worked! Do you know if its possible to do it where the new view controller is not stacked on top of the previous one?

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59499708/8374890 Do upvote it if it helps :)