# Layout issue with iOS 13 and Xcode 11

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

Opened up an existing project to do some updates and notices that there is now a space at the top of all of my view controllers.  This relays out to the device (iPhone X) when deployed.  See area outlined in red.  The area behind the green top bar is what I am talking about.  I have tried changing the layout constraints but no help.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Answer (score 0):

Apple introduced a new default card presentation. In order to force the fullscreen you have to specify it explicitly with:

```
let controller = UIViewController()
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen //or .overFullScreen for transparency
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```