# Extend UIView height (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, uiview

Sorry if I may come off abit of a newbie but does anyone know how I can just extend the height of my View non-programmatically in storyboard? If you look at the images attached, the view is not extended all the way to the top. This is only a prototype for iPhone X/11 so size constraints is optional for this.

IMAGES
https://ibb.co/vPSNTgS
https://ibb.co/NxgpQd9

Comment: This is the way modal presentations are handled on iPhone X/11.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Answer (score 0):

As Rohan stated This is the way modal presentations are handled on iOS 13
you can change its presentation style to full screen

ObjC

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
```

Swift

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

From **Storyboard**

Select segue then convert its kind to  modal ... it will show you option of Presentation. Select full screen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select destination controller from storyboard go to attribute inspector and click on presentation choose full screen.

[image: Please check following]