# How to show a full screen with Navigation bar instead of a form sheet

Tags: swift, navigationbar

I have a login page which is inside a navigation controller once logged in it takes you to a tab bar controller,
The problem i am having is that the Tab bar views are showing as forms sheets so i can still see the login Page at the top of the view as there is a gap because the Navigation bar is not showing 
which i have read this is the default behaves in iOS 13

How can i change this so it covers the full screen with my Navigation bar showing ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56435511/8447312

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Answer (score 0):

try the below

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen //or .overFullScreen for transparency
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```