# When going a ViewController to another it's showing like browser tabs, How can i remove it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When going a ViewController to another it's showing like browser tabs, How can I change it to normal? check below images

[image: now look like]

[image: and like this]

Comment: Show us the code. How are you going? What is the style?

Comment: You need to present your controller with fullscreen style.

Comment: This is the new default modal presentation style in iOS 13.  You can set `modalPresentationStyle = .fullscreen` to get full screen presentation

Comment: right now I am using Xcode 11.3.1 (11C504) but same code, when running in Xcode 10 all is normal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Comment: @Paulw11 where I can set modalPresentationStyle = .fullscreen to get full screen presentation?

Comment: @EtienneJézéquel Yes same