# Is there any way to get rid of short ViewController with storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

[image]

My Code is

```
else if indexPath.row == 4 {

            FUser.logOutCurrentUser { (success) in
                if success {
                    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
                    let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "welcome") as! Login_VC
                    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    self.alertController(title: "Alert !", message: "Network error. Try again in sometime.", titleAction: "Ok")
                }
            } // end of fuser
        } // end of else index 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `modalPresentationStyle` of your UIViewcontroller from `automatic` to `fullscreen`.

See https://medium.com/@hacknicity/view-controller-presentation-changes-in-ios-13-ac8c901ebc4e

You can also take a look at this post:
[Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Solution from this thread:

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen //or .overFullScreen for transparency
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can also change this property in the Xcode Interface Builder.