# how do i get my viewer controller to be full screen?

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an app using xcode (Swift) with out using the storyboard but i have a problem when a user logs in to the app they are transferred to the home page but the viewer controller does not reach the top of the screen and when i change to a different tab i can see the login screen in the background.

This is the code i use to get transferred to the home screen once the user logs in:

```
let mainTabVC = MainTabVC()
self.present(mainTabVC, animated: true,completion: nil)
```

is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the modal presentation style in `MainTabVC`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set  `modalPresentationStyle` of your controller [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621355-modalpresentationstyle)

```
 mainTabVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

> The presentation style determines how a modally presented view
>   controller is displayed onscreen. In a horizontally compact
>   environment, modal view controllers are always presented full-screen.
>   In a horizontally regular environment, there are several different
>   presentation options. The default value for this property is
>   UIModalPresentationStyle.automatic. For a list of possible
>   presentation styles, and their compatibility with the available
>   transition styles, see the UIModalPresentationStyle constant
>   descriptions.

Comment: you could mark this duplicate instead of adding answer...