# Navigation Controller segue is presented modally

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I tried to build a simple segue. Therefor I embedded a Navigation Controller and set it as the initial View Controller. I then created the segue (kind: show) to a different ViewController.
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdcKn.png)
Even the storyboard looks right and I can run the app without any Errors or Warnings.
But when I open the app in the simulator and press on the button to switch screens the new view pops up like a modal presentation.
[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTm4c.png)
None of this is done programmatically. To solve this issue I tried different segue kinds after that I rebuild the Navigation Controller and segue entirely but it changed nothing.

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56530134/503402

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Comment: I know how to get the new view in full screen but I won't get the Navigation bar from the Navigation Controller and the new view slides in from the bottom and not from the right, by using this attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I just created two view controllers, embedded a nav controller and then connected a button in the first view controller to the second. In the simulator, pressing the button showed the second view controller with a nav bar on top. Try deleting the current segue and nav controller, and then embed in the nav controller and create the segue again.

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3ydB.png)

[First page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSYzf.png)

[Second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt9gm.png)

Comment: I did but the same thing happens. The only thing that is different is, that I have 2 Storyboards and I'm using the Navigation Controller as reference because it is the initial view controller of this storyboard. But I don't know how this could change the behavior of the Navigation Controller.

Comment: How are you dragging your segue when connecting the first view controller with the second? I did a two finger tap and drag from the "first" button to the body of the second view controller.

Comment: Control drag. I build another xcode project and created a segue there and it works perfectly fine so I think I must have done something in my original project that changes the behavior of the Navigation Controller.

Comment: Yeah most likely. Did you end up figuring it out?

Comment: Not yet I will experiment a bit to figure out what triggers this behavior. I will then post it.