# Replace the viewcontroller without it appearing behind it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uimodalpresentationstyle

My issue occurs when changing the VC, the old VC continues to appear in the background (see [screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmd6A.png)). How can I fix it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sheet presentation style appears as a [card](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/modality/). To make it fullscreen use this.

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen //or .overFullScreen for transparency
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: And to change from storyboard to fullscreen, how's it going? The application won't use more memory knowing that the VCs stay in the background?

Comment: To change from storyboard follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57546875/7808861)

Answer (score 0):

If VC is to disappear, try to get rid of its reference - call the destructor - deinit, and then VC will be destroyed by ARC

Helpful link:
[Swift deinitialization and ARC](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Deinitialization.html)