# Issues with Segue in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, segue

I've been having trouble when I make a segue in the storyboard in Xcode. If I have two view controllers on the storyboard, it looks good. Once I make the segue connection, the view controller changes on the top. How do I solve this issue? Pictures are attached below.

Picture Before Segue:

[image]

Picture After Segue:

[image]

This happens after I "control + click and drag" on the button to the next storyboard, then click "Show".

Comment: a Beginner advice use Storyboard IDs instead of Segues, you won't regret it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Show presents your new screen with Modal Type. You can change the Navigation to Detail. You can also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen) if you would like to keep the modal Navigation but with the fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Select the `View Controller` which is destination view controller , then go in `attributes Inspector` and under `Presentation` tab, select `Full Screen`.

Answer (score 0):

With your ViewController is selected.

> Use Over Full Screen for transparency.
> [image]