# How to change presentation style of ViewController to fullscreen after it has been presented

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am needing to add a full screen button to my view controller to make the view full screen. Since iOS 13, it is now presented by default as a modal card-like view. The company I work for like the default modal view, but we want to give the user an option to go full screen as well. I've implemented a button on the view controller which runs the following:

```
- (IBAction)fullScreenButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
}
```

It doesn't do anything however. My question is how can I make my view controller go full screen, after it has already been presented on screen?

Comment: I believe you would need to dismiss it and present it again as fullscreen

Comment: ask for the NavigationController and set this one to full screen
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen