# Xcode black bar on top of view controller after connecting segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, uistoryboard

I have a problem with my Xcode project. The problem is that when I link one of my view controllers up to another with a segue a weird black bar appears on the top. Here's a video of that problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQLLZ.jpg

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the segue to the second ViewController is a "show", and the second VC will show like this:

[image]

If you want this VC to be full screen, click on the segue you created, change the "Kind" property to "Present Modally", and the "Presenttion" property to "Full Screen":

[image]