# Different colored header area

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I am new to swift development and I was wondering what is this area at the top of my view controller and how do I change it so it matches the rest of the view?

**View Controller Screenshot-**

[image]

Comment: Try giving colour to the main view of the view controller i.e. the view which is present above safe area.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Answer (score 0):

As @Tyler said, the area comes from the default presenting modal since iOS13.

But if you are asking how to get rid of it in storyboard (my guess from your image), try set the Size attribute in the attribute inspector to "Inferred".

You probably had set it to Page sheet, which show the appearance of a page when presented modally.

[image]
[image]