# How do I achieve this in Swift using Xcode 11?

Tags: swift, uiview, uimodalpresentationstyle

Since default Modal Presentation Style is now page sheet, some apps have this tiny grey rectangle on top of the view (inside the circle in green). Is there a way to add without create a custom UIView?

[image: MODAL]

Comment: Set the [`modalPresentationStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621355-modalpresentationstyle). If doing this via segue, you can set the style in IB. If doing it programmatically, set this after/during the instantiation of the destination view controller.

Comment: I've tried  all modalPresentationStyle  in IB and programmatically  but the "—" do not appears. My question is about the object inside the green circle.

Comment: I must have misunderstood the question. I thought you were just asking [how to make it appear full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen).

Comment: It's weird that this appears in the [HiG](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/modality/), but that they don't show us how to achieve it...

Comment: I know it's a just a little detail, but I thought that I'm the only strugling with this.