# Tab Bar Controller issue in UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

The tab bar controller formatting incorrectly, instead of showing the entire iPhone screen its coming off as a rectangle

how can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: It seems you have presented modally the `UITabBarController`, but not with the option fullscreen (since iOS13 if I remember correctly). So, how is shown the TabBar? By code? By segue? Set the correct option `modalPresentationStyle`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Comment: I have used the LoginViewController as a method of presenting the MainTabbarController which holds my 5 view controllers within that TabbarViewController. This is my code below but I am unsure if I shiuld be using the Login View Controller to show my Tab Controller

Comment: class LoginViewController : UIViewController {
  
        @IBAction func LoginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
              let mainTabController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabController") as! MainTabController
        mainTabController.selectedViewController = mainTabController.viewControllers?[0]
        present(mainTabController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    

}

Comment: See the related question in the comment, you'll see what you are missing: `modalPresentationStyle` to set. Also, it's better to put code in question (edit) instead of comment, where it's hard to read

Comment: Thank you that worked! before  just set it to present but I didn't add the modelPresentationStyle set to full screen ive been trying to do this all week so I thank you greatly for your help!

Comment: modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
modatTransitionStyle = .crossDisolve //and much more