# Setting up View controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In my app I have a piece of code that allows to go automatically from one Vc to another Vc after a short period of time. The problem is that when the second Vc pops out id doesn't cover up all the screen. How can I make it cover up the whole screen and not let the user go back? Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class InitialViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let delay : Double = 2.0    // 4 seconds here
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let firstViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstViewController") as! firstViewController
        self.present(firstViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Comment: Is your final goal to replace one controller with another or keep the first controller in memory for later use?

Answer (score 0):

You must present the controller modally with fullscreen. Then they cannot swipe from the top to dismiss the controller.

```
import UIKit

class InitialViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let delay : Double = 2.0    // 4 seconds here
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let firstViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstViewController") as! firstViewController
        firstViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(firstViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

}
```