# Prevent presenting view controller from changing size in background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

The current default behavior on presenting view controller modally is that the presenting view controller decreases size in background which shows the application window behind it with default window color.

I have the presented view controller at its default state. didn't change any transition properties:

```
self.present(presentedControler, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**How to prevent the presenting view controller from getting resized in background?**

> Note I want the presenting view controller to stay in fullscreen not
> the presented view controller.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)

Comment: I read, but I can, and it seems that I misunderdstood. It might also mean that your question wasn't clear. Since it's iOS default behavior, I'd use a custom segue/presentation style to produce the desired behavior. Side note, I didn't downvote*